# SharePoint imported list template are not shown when creating new list from it

Tags: sharepoint, list, templates, import, export

I have a SharePoint site that is used for only developing and testing. Now, I am creating my actual site by creating necessary objects, pages, parts etc.

I faced with this problem after I export my list templates from old site and import these templates to new one. All these imported templates are shown in "Galleries->List Templates". but they are not available when I attempted to create a list from these templates by going "Site Actions->More Options->List".

What will be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Activate Team Collaboration Lists Feature from Site Actions -->
Manage site features on the publishing site. This worked for me.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a problem with your languages, check this tutorial:
http://nikcharlebois.com/changing-sharepoint-list-template-language/

Language IDs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff463597.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are the Features required to support your list templates enabled in your target Site Collection / Site?

Comment: Do you have a clue about what feature must be enabled? I mean I couldn't find related feature with this issue.

Comment: In the first instance, ensure that the Features enabled in your source Site Collection / Site are also enabled in your target Site Collection / Site.

Comment: I have made them the same features enabled, but it doesn't work. 
Can it be related to my first site is team site, other site is publishing site?

Comment: Possibly. What happens if you create a team site as a target site and attempt to create your lists on that?

Comment: I did not try that. Indeed, creating publishing site is a requirement for me. Is it a dead end?

Comment: No. What are the types of your source lists e.g. are they Custom lists, Surveys, Events lists, etc?

Comment: One more comment....I just tried replicating my solution on my server, and it worked. Did you definitely ensure the same Features are enabled at both the Site Collection **and** Site level?

Comment: I recreated my lists just enable to use, I think it was a problem of the language incompatiblity, language of two sites are different. Anyway, thank you for replying.